# Ejercicio de método Burbuja en C

Tags: c

Crear un programa que contenga un arreglo de 10 elementos de tipo estructura, la estructura deberá contar con los siguientes miembros de tipo entero:

- `dia`
- `mes`
- `año`
- `numero de contrato`

El programa deberá realizar el ordenamiento (con cualquiera de los métodos vistos en clase) de las fechas de mayor a menor.

así es mi código, pero solo me acomoda las 2 fechas mayores con la posición correspondiente.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

int i, j, ord, aux, aux2, aux3, aux4, aux5, aux6;
int n= 10;

struct fechas
{
    int day[10] = {12, 15, 11, 10, 13, 14, 25, 26, 28, 29};
    int month[10]= {4, 9, 1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 10, 11};
    int year[10]= {1999, 1998, 2000, 2005, 2009, 2017, 2016, 2006, 1994, 2018};
}fecha;

i=1;
ord=0;

while(ord == 0)
{
    ord = 1;
    for(j=0; j<n-i; j++)
    {

        if(fecha.year[j] <= fecha.year[j+1])
        {
            aux= fecha.year[j];
            aux2= fecha.month[j];
            aux3= fecha.day[j];

            fecha.year[j] = fecha.year[j+1];
            fecha.month[j] = fecha.month[j+1];
            fecha.day[j] = fecha.day[j+1];

            fecha.year[j+1] = aux;
            fecha.month[j+1] = aux2;
            fecha.day[j+1] = aux3;
            ord = 0;
        }

        else if(fecha.month[j] <= fecha.month[j+1])
        {
            aux4= fecha.month[j];
            aux5= fecha.month[j];

            fecha.month[j] = fecha.month[j+1];
            fecha.day[j] = fecha.day[j+1];

            fecha.month[j+1] = aux4;
            fecha.day[j+1] = aux5;
            ord = 0;
        }

        else if(fecha.day[j] <= fecha.day[j+1])
        {
            aux6= fecha.day[j];

            fecha.day[j] = fecha.day[j+1];

            fecha.day[j+1] = aux6;
            ord = 0;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    printf("\n[ %d / %d / %d]", fecha.year[i], fecha.month[i], fecha.day[i]);
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿te han solucionado el problema? Por favor, revisa la respuesta que te proporcionaron y si es la solución a tu problema márcala como tal. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas noches, considero que no estas creando la estructura como corresponde.

Según entiendo acerca de tu ejercicio la estructura debiería ser de la siguiente forma:

```
struct contrato{
    int num_contrato;
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int año;
};
```

Luego de tener la estructura debes crear un arreglo de la misma:

```
contrato array_contratos[10];
```

Teniendo esto tendrás que insertarle valor a cada uno, pero aprovechando las variables que tienes, podrías hacerlo a través de un ciclo **for**:

```
for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){
    contrato aux;
    aux.dia = v_dia[i];
    aux.mes = v_mes[i];
    aux.año = v_año[i];
    aux.num_contrato = v_num_contrato[i];
    array_contratos[i] = aux;
}
```

Teniendo todos esos datos puedes aplicar el algoritmo de ordenamiento.

***Envío codigo completo:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Source.h"

static const int TAM = 10;

int main() {

    int v_dia[TAM] = { 12, 15, 11, 10, 13, 14, 25, 26, 10, 29 };
    int v_mes[TAM] = { 4, 1, 1, 3, 2, 7, 6, 5, 1, 11 };
    int v_año[TAM] = { 2005, 2017, 2000, 2005, 2009, 2017, 2016, 2006, 2017, 2018 };
    int v_num_contrato[TAM] = { 123,123,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };

    struct contrato {
        int num_contrato;
        int dia;
        int mes;
        int año;
    };

    contrato array_contratos[TAM];

    //LLENANDO EL ARREGLO DE ESTRUCTURAS CON INFORMACION DE LOS ARREGLOS POR SEPARADO
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        contrato con;
        con.dia = v_dia[i];
        con.mes = v_mes[i];
        con.año = v_año[i];
        con.num_contrato = v_num_contrato[i];
        array_contratos[i] = con;
    }

    printf("Editado por: VCHIROY\n\n********ANTES********\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        contrato con = array_contratos[i];
        printf("Contrato: %d\tFecha: %d-%d-%d\n", con.num_contrato, con.dia, con.mes, con.año);
    }


    /*
    ALGORTIMO DE ORDENAMIENTO
    */
    for (int i = 1; i < TAM; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TAM - 1; j++) {
            //ORDENAR AÑO
            if (array_contratos[j].año >= array_contratos[j + 1].año) {
                contrato aux_año = array_contratos[j];
                // ORDENAR MES
                for (int x = 0; x < TAM; x++) {
                    if (aux_año.año == array_contratos[x].año && array_contratos[x].mes >= aux_año.mes) {
                        contrato aux = array_contratos[x];
                        array_contratos[x] = array_contratos[j + 1];
                        array_contratos[j + 1] = aux;

                        /*
                        FALTA ORDERNAR POR DÍA
                        */
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    printf("\n\n********DESPUES********\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        contrato con = array_contratos[i];
        printf("Contrato: %d\tFecha: %d-%d-%d\n", con.num_contrato, con.dia, con.mes, con.año);
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    system("pause");
    system("exit");
    return 0;
}
```

***y el output:***

```
Editado por: VCHIROY

********ANTES********
Contrato: 123   Fecha: 12-4-2005
Contrato: 123   Fecha: 15-1-2017
Contrato: 3     Fecha: 11-1-2000
Contrato: 4     Fecha: 10-3-2005
Contrato: 5     Fecha: 13-2-2009
Contrato: 6     Fecha: 14-7-2017
Contrato: 7     Fecha: 25-6-2016
Contrato: 8     Fecha: 26-5-2006
Contrato: 9     Fecha: 10-1-2017
Contrato: 10    Fecha: 29-11-2018


********DESPUES********
Contrato: 3     Fecha: 11-1-2000
Contrato: 123   Fecha: 12-4-2005
Contrato: 4     Fecha: 10-3-2005
Contrato: 8     Fecha: 26-5-2006
Contrato: 5     Fecha: 13-2-2009
Contrato: 7     Fecha: 25-6-2016
Contrato: 123   Fecha: 15-1-2017
Contrato: 9     Fecha: 10-1-2017
Contrato: 6     Fecha: 14-7-2017
Contrato: 10    Fecha: 29-11-2018


Presione una tecla para continuar . . .
```

Espero te sirva...

Comment: Hay  que realizar unos ajustes al ordenamiento.